# Display accented letters in iTerm2

Tags: vim, terminal, iterm2

When I type accented letter in iTerm2, I get a strange behaviour. For instance when i type "sélectionner", iTerm2 displays "**sé lectionner**".

Preferences/Profiles/Terminal/Character Encoding is set to Unicode (UTF-8).

Any idea of what I should do to have iTerm2 display characters correctly?

Thanks

Comment: What font do you use? What are the language settings of your system? Of your shell?

Comment: Hi Romain, thanks for your reply. I'm using Source Code. My system is in english. I'm not sure what info you need about the shell though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure "prefs>profiles>text>treat ambiguous-width characters as double-width" is turned off.

See also [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=2831).